# How to pass a dictionary to a function as named parameters in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a dictionary with several items.

```
d = {}
d['name'] = 'Umair'
d['field'] = 'Programmer'
FunctionHere(name = d['name'], field = d['field'])
```

How can I pass that dictionary as named parameters without writing each value?

Comment: `FunctionHere(**d)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is:

```
FunctionHere(**d)
```

Documented in the section about *unpacking arguments* here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists